# How to mention a user/group in a new message to a channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I checked the samples/API references here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/connectors
- https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/GetStarted
- https://dev.outlook.com/Connectors/Reference

But cannot find how to mention someone in a new message to a channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatic @mentions are not currently supported by Microsoft Teams, and will probably not come soon.

There is [such a wish](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/c1668d5e-272e-ec11-b6e6-00224827bbc2) from the community in the MS uservoice portal, but it seems not to burn as much as other issues:

Comment: Downvoting, since it does not reflect the current state of affairs - see answer from Bill Bliss.

Comment: @Rich Moe - You mention 'soon'. Can you be more specific? It's been over a year and this still isn't available. Is there somewhere where we can see this, on a backlog or schedule of some sort?

Comment: Exactly, there is no time frame mentioned even in the latest update https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/17153099-webhook-needs-to-support-forced-notification-a-la

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht Upvoting as this is not a bot question, it's a webhook question. There is still no proper solution to this, it's stuck in the backlog.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry this was never answered. This feature was added months ago - there are SDK methods called addMentionToText (Node.js) and AddMentionToText (C#) - source and usage samples [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=addMentionToText).

There's also an example [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-template-bot/blob/d461411e3a73e66423d4ba762f737c7c4f9af0cf/src/dialogs/examples/teams/AtMentionDialog.ts) that's actually a bit more helpful. That example bot can be run very quickly on Glitch - repo and instructions are [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-template-bot).

Note that one of the challenges in using this API is that you have to have the user ID of the person you want to @ mention, and for that you need the team roster. Examples of how to do that are [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-template-bot/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=roster&type=).

Comment: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/17022934-notification-for-connectors this was the merged idea but probably I can follow the channel only, not push messages to mention someone special.

Comment: @YvesR There's this one for the mention support request on [uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32313991-allow-webhooks-extensions-to-mention-individuals).

Comment: @JohnStephenson Yeah, saw this already and commented. Development on our side in teams looks a bit slow, they probably focus on migrate Skype for business instead of make a valuable competitor to slack :)

Comment: Thanks Bill, is there any way to do this with the REST API? or inside a message posted to a channel via the REST API?