# How to mention user in microsoft teams?

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I am using a webhook url to post messages to a teams in Microsoft teams. Now i want to be able to mention users as well but when i send

```
{ "text": "hello world @user1"}
```

I just get plain text like `hello world @user1` .

I am looking for a way to mention the user.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to mention a user/group in a new message to a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440803/how-to-mention-a-user-group-in-a-new-message-to-a-channel/).

Comment: Not a duplicate i guess, Although method is available in sdk's for .net and node.js but still not finding a way to include @mentions when need to send message in a team using powershell and webhook URL and it's 2019!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mention a user/group in a new message to a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440803/how-to-mention-a-user-group-in-a-new-message-to-a-channel)