# how to mention user/channel in microsoft teams channel in an Incoming Webhook message through REST API?

Tags: rest, botframework, microsoft-teams

tried to follow answer in [Question 41440803](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41440803/6346058) but I'd like to find a way to post JSON message to an Incoming Webhook (no need for building a custom bot service), just invoking REST actions directly from my scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Updates:
[User mention in Incoming Webhook with Adaptive Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#user-mention-in-incoming-webhook-with-adaptive-cards)

Check the answer from kostasvs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69365035/576503

---

Only the [Office 365 connector card](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) format is supported over Incoming Webhook. Connectors do not support @mentions yet.

Comment: It is now supportet see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494475/mention-via-incoming-webhook-in-ms-teams-using-messagecard